# Trouble Classifying Function of Cell Array in MATLAB "parfor" Loop

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

So I've been doing research all morning and cannot figure out why this code won't run.

Originally the code was:

```
nSim = 100;
nTs = 40;
nRep = 10;
m1 = NaN(nTs,nSim);
meanM1 = NaN(nTs,nRep);
delta = [1/400,1/400,-1/400]';
d = -0.05;
dataQCell = cell(nSim*nRep,1);
for jj=1:nSim*nRep
  dataQCell{jj} = rand(3,nTs);
end

matlabpool('open',10)
parfor ii=1:nRep
  for jj=1:nSim
    for tt=1:nTs
      if tt>1
        m1(tt,jj) = m1(tt-1,jj) + delta'* dataQCell{(ii-1)*nSim+jj,1}(1:3,tt)+d;
      else
        m1(tt,jj) = delta'* dataQCell{(ii-1)*nSim+jj,1}(1:3,tt) + d;
      end
    end
  end

  meanM1(tt,ii) = mean(m1,2);
end
matlabpool close force
```

My initial thought was that the culprit was

```
m1(tt,jj) = m1(tt-1,jj) + deltaQ'* dataQCell{(ii-1)*nSim+jj,1}(1:3,tt) + d;
```

as the index of `dataQCell` is a function of indices (`ii`,`jj`).

Note I've commented out `meanM1`line and I still get the same error.

My first attempt at a solution was to break the (`nSim*nRep` X 1) cell into `nRep` parts by modifying the code

```
nSim = 100;
nTs = 40;
nRep = 10;
m1 = NaN(nTs,nSim);
meanM1 = NaN(nTs,nRep);
deltaQ = [1/400,1/400,-1/400]';
d = -0.05;

dataQCell = cell(nSim*nRep,1);
for jj=1:nSim*nRep
  dataQCell{jj} = rand(3,nTs);
end

dataRepCell = cell(nRep,1);
for ii=1:nRep
  dataRepCell{ii} = dataQCell{(ii-1)*nSim+1:ii*nSim};
end

matlabpool('open',10)
parfor ii=1:nRep
  for jj=1:nSim
    for tt=1:nTs
      if tt>1
        m1(tt,jj) = m1(tt-1,jj) + deltaQ'* dataRepCell{ii}{jj}(1:3,tt)+d;
      else
        m1(tt,jj) = deltaQ'* dataRepCell{ii}{jj}(1:3,tt) + d;
      end
    end
  end

  meanM1(tt,ii) = mean(m1,2);
end
matlabpool close force
```

But I get the same "Unable to classify variable 'm1'", error.

Comment: Please try to turn your code into a [mcve]: remove **all unnecessary code** and provide all inputs so that we can run your code ourselves and reproduce the error.

Comment: Code should be able to execute now. Only thing is I believe matlabpool is not used in latest version of MATLAB

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `m1` was not allowed to be classified as temporary variable as I preallocated the matrix before the `parfor` loop. The solution is to run `m1=Nan(nTs,nSim)` inside the `parfor` loop.